# Play video in android using unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to play a video in android using unity. I don't want to play video on full screen but on a particular cube like object. How to do it ?

Comment: Did you not find this in your research: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html

Comment: I have seen it. But it says videos will be played only in full screen in android. I want to play like movie texture.

Comment: You need Unity 5.6 beta. Check this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it. But it doesn't mention anything about that video will be played on android