# Integrate ffmpeg with unity via plugin

Tags: plugins, ffmpeg, unity-game-engine

I need to integrate ffmpeg into unity via a plugin.
Is there tutorials/blog to integrate ffmpeg with unity by a plugin.

Comment: You don't have to. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video)

Comment: I am trying to play the video for hololens, where the unity Video player component doesnt work/crash. That is why i am trying to use ffmpeg

Comment: That's a bug. My suggestion to you for this and your other question is to file for a bug then wait for Unity to release the next few beta version. This is better than starting the process of marshaling between C++ and C#. This is a complicated subject and will take so much time to even do.

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up using Easy Movie Texture, it uses ffmpeg player. Unity's beta player can not decode my video properly (h264 encoded by ffmpeg). I would love to have a tutorial on this one as well!

Comment: MediaDecoder project has source released for video player(unity marshalling) https://github.com/ViveSoftware/MediaDecoder plz use it for reference

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen in Unity. The Easy Movie Texture plugin used this for video decoding.