# WWW.Movie not working unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, videotexture

I have been looking at the WWW.movie documentation and i can seam to get it working.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-movie.html

The code below is attached to a cube containing both the GUI Texture and Audio Source Components. if anyone can help me to get this working i would be very greatful.

I am using unity 5.5.1 and am creating a VR application.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TouchMovie1 : MonoBehaviour {
 public string url = "file://C:/Users/blobbymatt/VRLibrary/Videos/video.ogv";

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

     StartCoroutine(loadAndPlay ());
 }



 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }

 IEnumerator loadAndPlay() {
     // Start download
     var www = new WWW(url);

     // Make sure the movie is ready to start before we start playing
     var movieTexture = www.movie;
     while (!movieTexture.isReadyToPlay) { 
     yield return null;
         Debug.Log("Loading");
     }



     var gt = GetComponent< GUITexture > ();

     // Initialize gui texture to be 1:1 resolution centered on screen
     gt.texture = movieTexture;


     // Assign clip to audio source
     // Sync playback with audio
     var aud = GetComponent< AudioSource > ();
     aud.clip = movieTexture.audioClip;

     // Play both movie & sound
     movieTexture.Play();
     aud.Play();
     yield return null;
 }
```

}

Comment: is there an error message?

Comment: No error message, it just doesn't play. I can also see that the video has attached to the GUITexture but there's nothing in the game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `GUITexture` because it obsolete. If you want to display video, do it on the [`RawImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html) component with `GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = yourMovieTexture;`.

If you want to do it on a 3D Model then do it on the `MeshRenderer` component with `GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = yourMovieTexture`.

If using Unity 5.6 and above:

Replace

```
www.movie;
```

with

```
www.GetMovieTexture();
```

There is a new API to play video in *Unity 5.6*. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video).

With the `RawImage` component, you can do it with the code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TouchMovie1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string url = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv";
    public RawImage videDisplay;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(loadAndPlay());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator loadAndPlay()
    {
        // Start download
        var www = new WWW(url);

        // Make sure the movie is ready to start before we start playing
        var movieTexture = www.movie;

        //Assign the Texture to the RawImage
        videDisplay.texture = movieTexture;

        while (!movieTexture.isReadyToPlay)
        {
            yield return null;
            Debug.Log("Loading");
        }

        // Assign clip to audio source
        // Sync playback with audio
        var aud = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        aud.clip = movieTexture.audioClip;

        // Play both movie & sound
        movieTexture.Play();
        aud.Play();
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you so much!!!! i spent the better part of a day trying to work this out :D

Comment: You are welcome. I even forgot to completely remove `GUITexture` from the code. Just did that.

Comment: www.movie says OBSOLETE in the Docs. 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-movie.html

Comment: @omarojo Don't use this. `MovieTexture` will be deprecated soon. See the link in my answer that shows new way to play video in Unity. This answer will remain here for those using old Unity version.

Comment: You are right, I didnt read properly. On the other hand I found this component : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-VideoPlayer.html but it doesnt work with my sample videos, it crashes unity entirely: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Examplevideo.ogv or https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

Comment: *"On the other hand I found this component : docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-VideoPlayer.html"* I don't think you read right again because that VideoPlayer "component" is what I linked in my answer. Take a moment and read that. If you have a problem with it, you can create new question with your code and mention your Unity version + platform it is crashing on

Comment: VideoPlayer has a huge problem on Android. The VideoPlayer.prepare() runs on the main thread! Therefore, it will freeze your app while preparing video. Ugh! I will stick to MovieTexture until that is resolved.

Comment: @TatiOverflow Note that you did not answer/do or address anything I said in my [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video?noredirect=1#comment79629011_41144054) comment. Good luck with MovieTexture which doesn't even work on mobile devices. Please, do not continue to spam my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video?noredirect=1#comment79629011_41144054) Video questions/answers. If you have a question, create a new one.