# Firebase Messaging in Unity : Device is going to hot

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

this is my situation.

- using Unity.
- using firebase messaging SDK for unity.
- using the android phone.
- using google play service in my project.

I installed the latest version of firebase messaging SDK to my unity project.

it works well, has no problem.

but Firebase messaging SDK makes my phone so hot.

I think this SDK is using many CPU resources.

it's not happened before installing firebase SDK to my project.

if I turn off the app or go to background, it's cooling down so fast.

I don't want to make a heater app with firebase OMG!

help me plz...

Comment: *"I don't want to make a heater app with firebase OMG!"*....My comment is not helpful but you can actually put your question as an here on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42735449/3785314) post and solve another man's problem.

Comment: [ Programmer] wow this is the answer to his question seriously !!