# Get current frame Texture from VideoPlayer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It is stated in this post [Using new Unity VideoPlayer and VideoClip API to play video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video#) that one can "retrieve texture for each frame if needed"

What's the proper way to get the current frame as a Texture2D, please?

**EDIT:**

After the answer I did this but it's not working:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class AverageColorFromTexture : MonoBehaviour {

    public VideoClip videoToPlay;
    public Light lSource;

    private Color targetColor;
    private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
    private VideoSource videoSource;
    private Renderer rend;
    private Texture tex;
    private AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start()
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;
        StartCoroutine(playVideo());
    }

    IEnumerator playVideo()
    {

        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        videoPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

        //Disable Play on Awake for both Video and Audio
        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;
        audioSource.playOnAwake = false;

        videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;
        videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;
        videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
        videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);

        //Set video To Play then prepare Audio to prevent Buffering
        videoPlayer.clip = videoToPlay;
        videoPlayer.Prepare();

        //Wait until video is prepared
        while (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
        {
            Debug.Log("Preparing Video");
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Done Preparing Video");

        //Assign the Texture from Video to Material texture
        tex = videoPlayer.texture;
        rend.material.mainTexture = tex;

        //Enable new frame Event
        videoPlayer.sendFrameReadyEvents = true;

        //Subscribe to the new frame Event
        videoPlayer.frameReady += OnNewFrame;

        //Play Video
        videoPlayer.Play();

        //Play Sound
        audioSource.Play();

        Debug.Log("Playing Video");
        while (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Video Time: " + Mathf.FloorToInt((float)videoPlayer.time));
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Done Playing Video");
    }

    void OnNewFrame(VideoPlayer source, long frameIdx)
    {
        Texture2D videoFrame = (Texture2D)source.texture;

        targetColor = CalculateAverageColorFromTexture(videoFrame);
        lSource.color = targetColor ;
    }


    Color32 CalculateAverageColorFromTexture(Texture2D tex)
    {
        Color32[] texColors = tex.GetPixels32();
        int total = texColors.Length;
        float r = 0;
        float g = 0;
        float b = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            r += texColors[i].r;
            g += texColors[i].g;
            b += texColors[i].b;
        }
        return new Color32((byte)(r / total) , (byte)(g / total) , (byte)(b / total) , 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that properly in three steps:

1. Enable new frame event by setting [`VideoPlayer.sendFrameReadyEvents`](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-sendFrameReadyEvents.html) to `true`.
2. Subscribe to the [`VideoPlayer.frameReady`](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-frameReady.html) event
3. The function you assigned to the [`VideoPlayer.frameReady`](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-frameReady.html) event will be called when new frame is available. Just access the video frame from the `VideoPlayer` it will pass into the parameter by casting [`VideoPlayer.texture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-texture.html) to `Texture2D`.

That's it.

---

In code:

Before `video.Play()` add these:

```
// Enable new frame Event
videoPlayer.sendFrameReadyEvents = true;

// Subscribe to the new frame Event
videoPlayer.frameReady += OnNewFrame;
```

This is your `OnNewFrame` function signature.

```
void OnNewFrame(VideoPlayer source, long frameIdx)
{
    Texture2D videoFrame = (Texture2D)source.texture;
    // Do anything with the videoFrame Texture.
}
```

*It's worth noting that it's costly to enable that event. Make sure that you need each frame before doing this.*

Both `Texture2D videoFrame = (Texture2D)source.texture;` and and `Texture2D videoFrame = source.texture as Texture2D;` failed.

I put `Debug.Log(source.texture);` inside the `OnNewFrame` function and got:

> TempBuffer 294 320x240 (UnityEngine.RenderTexture)

So, it looks like the `Video.texture` property is returning `RenderTexture` type not `Texture` type like it should.

We have to convert the `RenderTexture` to `Texture2D`.

```
void Start()
{
    videoFrame = new Texture2D(2, 2);]
    ...
}

//Initialize in the Start function
Texture2D videoFrame;

void OnNewFrame(VideoPlayer source, long frameIdx)
{
    RenderTexture renderTexture = source.texture as RenderTexture;

    if (videoFrame.width != renderTexture.width || videoFrame.height != renderTexture.height)
    {
        videoFrame.Resize(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height);
    }
    RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
    videoFrame.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
    videoFrame.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = null;

    targetColor = CalculateAverageColorFromTexture(videoFrame);
    lSource.color = targetColor;
}
```

The complete code from your question:

```
public class AverageColorFromTexture : MonoBehaviour
{
    public VideoClip videoToPlay;
    public Light lSource;

    private Color targetColor;
    private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
    private VideoSource videoSource;
    private Renderer rend;
    private Texture tex;
    private AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start()
    {
        videoFrame = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        Application.runInBackground = true;
        StartCoroutine(playVideo());
    }

    IEnumerator playVideo()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        videoPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

        //Disable Play on Awake for both Video and Audio
        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;
        audioSource.playOnAwake = false;

        videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;
        videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;
        videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
        videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);

        //Set video To Play then prepare Audio to prevent Buffering
        videoPlayer.clip = videoToPlay;
        videoPlayer.Prepare();

        //Wait until video is prepared
        while (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
        {
            Debug.Log("Preparing Video");
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Done Preparing Video");

        //Assign the Texture from Video to Material texture
        tex = videoPlayer.texture;
        rend.material.mainTexture = tex;

        //Enable new frame Event
        videoPlayer.sendFrameReadyEvents = true;

        //Subscribe to the new frame Event
        videoPlayer.frameReady += OnNewFrame;

        //Play Video
        videoPlayer.Play();

        //Play Sound
        audioSource.Play();

        Debug.Log("Playing Video");
        while (videoPlayer.isPlaying)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Video Time: " + Mathf.FloorToInt((float)videoPlayer.time));
            yield return null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Done Playing Video");
    }

    //Initialize in the Start function
    Texture2D videoFrame;

    void OnNewFrame(VideoPlayer source, long frameIdx)
    {
        RenderTexture renderTexture = source.texture as RenderTexture;


        if (videoFrame.width != renderTexture.width || videoFrame.height != renderTexture.height)
        {
            videoFrame.Resize(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height);
        }
        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        videoFrame.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        videoFrame.Apply();
        RenderTexture.active = null;

        targetColor = CalculateAverageColorFromTexture(videoFrame);
        lSource.color = targetColor;
    }

    Color32 CalculateAverageColorFromTexture(Texture2D tex)
    {
        Color32[] texColors = tex.GetPixels32();
        int total = texColors.Length;
        float r = 0;
        float g = 0;
        float b = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            r += texColors[i].r;
            g += texColors[i].g;
            b += texColors[i].b;
        }
        return new Color32((byte)(r / total), (byte)(g / total), (byte)(b / total), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply and for taking time to code your answer!
...but I get a 'Cannot convert type UnityEngine.Video.VideoSource to UnityEngine.Texture2D' error when casting the VideoPlayer texture!

Comment: My answer said twice that you convert the `VideoPlayer.texture` **not** `VideoPlayer` to `Texture2D`. Please cop the function from my answer directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I've done exactly as you said...but still getting a casting error on the `Texture2D videoFrame = (Texture2D)source.texture;` inside the OnNewFrame function!


Would you please help me point what I'm doing wrong?


Thanks

Comment: Check my EDITED answer. I didn't try my solution. I just did and found the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer it solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974403/convert-videoplayer-texture-as-texture2d-in-unity3?noredirect=1#comment82920712_47974403

Comment: But i am still unable to understand that why rendertexture.active has used and resize function.

Comment: `videoPlayer.texture` returns `RenderTexture` not `Texture` or `Texture2D`.  To convert `RenderTexture` to `Texture`, you have to save the `RenderTexture` to `RendeRenderTexture.active` which makes it the active Texture in this frame. You can now use `ReadPixels` to capture it since  `ReadPixels` is used to capture pixels block area from the currently **active** `RenderTexture`. The `Resize` function is used so that I do not have to create new `Resize` every frame that `OnNewFrame` function is called which is expensive. I simply resize it if the frame changes size which happens sometimes.