# Getting color range of pixel block in video texture in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get an average color from a specific 4x4 area in a video texture on every update. It can either be black or white, but because I'm streaming the video and the resolution differs from time to time it might also be grayish. I need to find out more precisely if it's "almost black" or more on the white/light gray side of the spectrum.

I'm very new to c# and unity. I found Texture2D.GetPixel or Texture2D.GetPixels32 might be better, but I'm really not sure how I can do that from a video texture.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Where is the video code?

Comment: I'm currently using UniversalMediaPlayer to stream the video on any object (from the unity asset store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747285/get-current-frame-texture-from-videoplayer/42747609#42747609) post. It looks like you are doing the-same thing as that person which is to get Texture from an image and average the pixel.

The reason I don't consider this a duplicate is because you want to get a pixels from specific(4x4) area not all pixels from the texture.

> Texture2D.GetPixel or Texture2D.GetPixels32 might be better,

Because you want to do this on speficic pixels, you can't do it with `Texture2D.GetPixel` or `Texture2D.GetPixels32`. You don't even need the *UniversalMediaPlayer* plugin you are using.

You can do this with the [`GetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) function. Notice the *'s'* at the end.

This is the function prototype:

```
Color[] GetPixels(int x, int y, int blockWidth, int blockHeight);
```

Depending on the position of the pixels you want to read from the Texture it should look something like this:

```
Color[] texColors = tex.GetPixels(0, 0, 4, 4);
```

You need to use that instead of `Color32[] texColors = tex.GetPixels32();` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747285/get-current-frame-texture-from-videoplayer/42747609#42747609) answer.

**Note**:

You can still use your *UniversalMediaPlayer* video plugin if you prefer it over Unity's new VideoPlayer. *The [`GetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) solution should still work.*

Comment: Thank you so much Programmer! It's so nice to have people like you help out beginners like myself and not treat us like idiots for not learning the language inside out first. I wish there was a way to repay you more than just a "checkmark".

Comment: Also, thank you for explaining the code really well.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to add code(if necessary) to your future questions so that your question wont be down-voted.