# Unity App freezes when loading Multiple Videos on same Scene

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine

When navigating from menu to a Scene that contains 8, 1-minutes MP4 videos, that are played using new VideoPlayer script on RawImage component. I am using Unity 5.6.0b11 beta version.

In the scene that I am trying to navigate has prefabs that loads videos in list thumbnails, previously I was loading Images instead of Videos and it was working fine, now when trying to load video it freezes for than 38 seconds on Axon 7 (4GB RAM) and 32 seconds on One Plus 3 (6 GB RAM) but does not lags at all when playing on Unity Player itself.

Script I used for VideoPlayer is from this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video/).

```
button.onClick.AddListener(new UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction(() =>
{
   SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("SceneSponsors");
   StartCoroutine(CloseMenu());
}));
```

Is there a way, I can work around with the Slow Loading Scenes or pre-load them in Background when `mainScene` is loaded on the App start and navigate in need.

I saw [somewhere](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/instantiate-from-resource-folder-with-android-player-is-too-slow) `Resources.Load()` also makes it slow on Android Devices, but I've tested by removing all Resources.Load() which I was using to load image sprites but the problem was still there.

**Edit:**
Here's my `CloseMenu()` functions it is only used to swipe and move the menu panel. P.S the App freezes only on loading that particular Scene, and works smoothly for other.

```
IEnumerator CloseMenu()
{
    if (IsOpen)
    {
        Vector3 pos = MainMenuWindow.transform.position;
        iTween.ColorUpdate(CloseArea, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0f), .6f);
        iTween.MoveTo(MainMenuWindow.gameObject, new Vector3(Screen.width, pos.y, pos.z), .6f);
        IsOpen = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
        CloseArea.transform.position = new Vector3(-240 * ScaleFact, CloseArea.transform.position.y, CloseArea.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**
I am loading VideoPlayer on RawImage using Script. Here's what RawImage looks like in [Play mode along with VideoPlayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URT3Y.jpg), and in [inactive mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw3iG.jpg).

Comment: What does your `CloseMenu` function look like?

Comment: @Programmer I have added the function. BTW App freezes only on loading that particular Scene, and works smoothly for other

Comment: Hmm there is nothing much going on in the `CloseMenu` function. 38 seconds is too much. Please check codes that you run in the OnEnable, Awake or Start functions. Disable them all then re-enable them one by one. You will find which one causing the problem. Please, post that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my case of problem. I had to make some changes on the `VideoPlayer` API Script I was using from this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In the script I was using from that link. The Co-routine was started inside the `Start()` function, that made the videos in 8 different prefab, to load at once even they were in pause mode.

So I added a new function `PlayVideoOnClick()` and attached it to the **Click Event** of the `RawImage`, so now the video will be loaded only if the `RawImage` is clicked.

Changed from

```
public void Start()
{
    Application.runInBackground = true;
    StartCoroutine(playVideo());

}
```

To

```
public void PlayVideoOnclick()
{
    Application.runInBackground = true;
    StartCoroutine(playVideo());

}
```

P.S: You can also see my YouTube [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGA3jMBDjHk) and [Blog on Playing Videos smoothly in Unity](http://justcode.me/unity2d/how-to-play-videos-on-unity-using-new-videoplayer/).

Answer (score 1):

It is a well known bug that loading big scenes using LoadSceneAsync may block the gpu completely several seconds (completely unnoticeable in the editor), i´ve also been following this for quite some time now,
From the forums:
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/starting-async-load-causes-massive-lag-spike.288755/ 
Official unity Issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/loading-a-scene-async-creates-huge-performance-spikes-for-the-gpu

Comment: What do you mean by Big Scene. Why is videos of 2Mb filesize, 8 of them loading from internet. Is 16-20Mb also a big scene.