# Play video in Unity 5.5 Personal edition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I looked at the MovieTexture class, to play videos from Unity's C# scripting, but MovieTexture is for Unity Pro, and I don't have the Pro version.

I also looked at PlayFullScreenMovie, to play videos, but that works only if I import the video as an asset inside Unity's Project folder.

My question is: Is there a way to play a video in Unity Personal edition, without importing the video as an asset? Like, can I use the video's file location (filepath) in the computer as the source url to play the video from? Thanks.

Comment: I thought we talked about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video). Why not use Unity 5.6?

Comment: yes yu were very helpful with that but the problem is I'm not allowed to use Unity 5.6 beta lol. I must use that 5.5 edition and that's the restriction. Otherwise, I would've been so happy to use that 5.6 edition

Comment: You haven't said why you are not allowed to use 5.6. Anyways, check my answer. Those are the only options you have now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I looked at the MovieTexture class to play videos from Unity's C#
>   scripting but MovieTexture is for Unity Pro and I don't have the Pro
>   version

*Not true*. After Unity 5.0 release, pro only API and tools in Unity became available in all version of Unity. You **can** use `MovieTexture` in Unity 5.5.

> I also looked at PlayFullScreenMovie to play videos but that works
>   only if I import the video as an asset inside Unity's Project folder

If your goal is to play video from the internet, url, local network or folder, forget about `PlayFullScreenMovie`. It's not made for that.

> Like can I use the video's file location (filepath) in the computer as
>   the source url to play the video from?

You can do this with `MovieTexture`. Note that there is a big limitation with  `MovieTexture`. For example, I've never seen it play .mp4 video before. It plays .ogg movie. Since you don't want to use [Unity 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video), you are very limited to things you can do with `MovieTexture`. It can't play video on mobile devices.

```
MovieTexture movieTexture;
AudioSource vidAudio;
public RawImage rawImage;

void Start()
{
    WWW www = new WWW("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv");
    movieTexture = www.GetMovieTexture();
    rawImage.texture = movieTexture;

    vidAudio = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    vidAudio.clip = movieTexture.audioClip;
}

void Update()
{
    if (movieTexture.isReadyToPlay && !movieTexture.isPlaying)
    {
        movieTexture.Play();
        vidAudio.Play();
    }

    if (movieTexture.isPlaying)
    {
        rawImage.texture = movieTexture;
    }
}
```

That remaining option left is to buy a video plugin or make one. These are very expensive so here are the top working ones.  [AVPro Video](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56355) and [Easy Movie Texture](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032).

Comment: oh ok now it makes sense. The fact that Movietexture can be used for personal edition is very helpful. The reason I can't use 5.6 beta is because I started off the project in 5.5 and didn't want to switch to a new version. i dont have any intensions of playing videos in mobile just pc. this is very helpful. thank you

Comment: *"I dont have any intensions of playing videos in mobile just pc"* MovieTexture should be fine in this case as long as you are only playing .ogg or ogv videos. Anything else will be a problem. Unity 5.6 will be released this month and to be honest, it what you are looking for which is playing video. That's the biggest feature in 5.6. A video player that plays .ogg file only is pretty much useless so you may have to take some time off and start upgrading your app to 5.6.

Comment: wow man i was thinking about playing like avi files but this will have to do for now. thank you so much for this information