# How to apply and play a video from the Unity Streaming Assets folder as a texture (MovieTexture)

Tags: c#, video, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, textures

I am trying to get a video (.ogv) from the Streaming Assets folder, apply it on to a surface and play it. (C# code added below) - Unity 5 Personal

```
void Start () {
 private MovieTexture myMoviePlayerTexture;

 string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "test.ogv");

 WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + filePath);
 Renderer r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
 r.material.mainTexture = www.movie;
 www.movie.Play();
}
```

C# Script added to a simple plane.

However when I add the MovieTexture to a plane (from assets folder) it plays without any problems.

```
((MovieTexture)GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture).Play();
```

edit: the Problem: the video does not play from the Streaming Assets folder, it appears as if a material is loaded but it does not play.

Any help appriciated. Thanks.

EDIT

This is the game view: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFssl.jpg) and this is the folder structure [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ediw6.jpg) nothing fancy just some test videos

Comment: What's the problem?  You never explained what problems you are having

Comment: @programmer Sorry, The video does not play. It appears that some material is loaded but it does not play fromt he Streaming Assets folder

Comment: What platform are you testing this on? Can you put a screenshot of what the folder you put the video in looks like?

Comment: @Programmer This is the game view: [link](http://imgur.com/CJ5NGTx) and this is the folder structure [link](http://imgur.com/htDmCtk) nothing fancy just some test videos

Comment: @Programmer I have also tried the Assets > StreamingAssets path but to no avail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your question is not even compiling. There are so many errors.

Anyways, don't play the video directly from the `WWW` object with `www.movie.Play();`. Get the MovieTexture from `WWW` first then play the video from there. Also, check if `MovieTexture.isReadyToPlay` is `true` before playing the video. You can do this in a `coroutine` or the `Update()` function.

Make sure that the *test.ogv* video is in the *StreamingAssets* folder. Your screenshot does not show what's inside the *StreamingAssets* folder.

Finally, playing video on a plane is now old. You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879536/3785314) play Video on Unity's *RawImage* which is easier to work with in Unity.

I can't tell which *Unity 5* version you are using but please update to *5.5* or above then use the code below:

```
MovieTexture myMoviePlayerTexture;
void Start()
{
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "test.ogv");

    WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + filePath);
    Renderer r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    myMoviePlayerTexture = www.GetMovieTexture();

    r.material.mainTexture = myMoviePlayerTexture;
}

void Update()
{
    if (myMoviePlayerTexture.isReadyToPlay && !myMoviePlayerTexture.isPlaying)
    {
        myMoviePlayerTexture.Play();
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that `MovieTexture` is now deprecated. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video) post for the newsiest method to play video.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and solution. I want to play the video on an object, will that still be possible with RawImage? I tried using your solution but I am getting an error [link](http://imgur.com/niaoUj3) for the www.GetMovieTexture(); line. I am using Unity 5.5.2f1.

Comment: If you just want to play video then use RawImage. It will show on the screen. If you want the video to show on a 3D Object like plane or cube then use the solution in my answer. I don't know what you are doing but before RawImage, playing video with plane was almost the only way to display the video. This is not true anymore with the RawImage. The decision is totally up to you.

Comment: Sorry for that error. I used Unity 5.6 to make this solution. You can replace that part with `www.movie`.

Comment: Thank you, Trying your solution now and downloading the 5.6beta.

Comment: Thank you, I think this will help well in what I am trying to achieve.