# Unity 5.6, What is the best approach to make "VR" video player (not 360 video!)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I want to make VR video player in Unity but what is the best approach to accomplish this?

My original idea was set 2 cameras and 2 spheres for both eyes and use shader to display the video. However I also want some UI in the scene so if I make UI element in the scene, that means I need to make another duplicate every time for every single UI element.
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5hIF.jpg)

Is there more efficient way to accomplish this task? I just started to use Unity so I don't know a lot of things in Unity. 
And sorry for my English, I'm not an English native.

Comment: This post is way too broad/opinion based for SO...

Comment: Create two spheres then render the video to RenderTexture and then show the video on the two spheres.... Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004339/play-360-stereoscopic-video-with-videoplayer/43006526#43006526) post and let me know if that works.

Comment: You say no 360 but you actually are making a `VR 360 video` with those spheres