# Ozo Player sdk streaming 360 video through .mpd file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I am using ozo player sdk plugin for playing 360 video in Unity3d. Local video is playing from the streaming assets folder in unity, it works fine. When i am playing video from server using .mpd file, sdk not able to play video please help me.

file Url : 
[http://35.185.12.162:1935/3S%20AWS%20Mediacache/*definst*/mp4:amazons3/3stagevr/sample2_TB.mp4/manifest.mpd](http://35.185.12.162:1935/3S%20AWS%20Mediacache/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/3stagevr/sample2_TB.mp4/manifest.mpd)

Comment: Are you sure that Ozo Player sdk can play .mpd file? Does it mention this on its page? I suggest you use video types such as mp4....

Comment: Also, you don't need plugins to play video anymore. You should be using Unity's [new API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video) for that.

Comment: yes i am sure they mention in there document https://ozo.nokia.com/media/custom/upload/OZO_Player_SDK_Product_Specifications.pdf play VOD and live streaming also.

Comment: i suggest you use video texture and put your texture on a sphere - i use this for playing 360 vr

Comment: I also used google VR sdk play 360 video from the .mpd file. In the sdk demo scene .mpd file is working fine it is streaming from the server but while i am playing my video http://35.185.12.162:1935/3S%20AWS%20Mediacache/definst/mp4:amazons3/3stagevr/sample2_TB.mp4/manifest.mpd url using google VR. Sound is playing but video is not displaying it blackout the screen. I don't know the reason why it is happening.