# Get current frame number / time of video in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing a problem, please help me if it is possible.

I'm practicing unity and I'm trying to make sth for myself. And I'm playing a video using UI and canvas raw image and what I need is this:

I want to tell animator to start a special animation when the movie reaches a specific frame or time for example when it reaches at 10 seconds I want to make the movie stop and that animation be triggered.

I don't have any problem with playing or pausing my video or triggering animations in animators...

My problem is that I don't know how to get the number of current frame playing in movie using script

I tried using time functions to solve my problem but it has two disadvantages , first its not accurate !! each time it results in a small different out come and I don know exactly why , second it becomes hard if I change something else for example actions before that movie

In short my question is this: is there any way to get the current frame number of a movie using script in unity ? ( a movie which is playing using UI and canvas and raw image )

Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: What  have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the current frame number of a movie using
>   script in unity ?

**Yes**. You can obtain the current video frame with the [`VideoPlayer.frame`](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-frame.html) variable.

Note that it works like an array index. `0` is the first frame and `1` is the second frame.

---

You seem to confuse video frame with video time in the title of this question. They are two different stuff.

You can obtain the video time with [`VideoPlayer.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-time.html). You just check when it is 10 seconds in the `Update` function then do something.

```
VideoPlayer vidPlayer = null;
void Update()
{
    if (vidPlayer.time == 10)
    {
        ///
    }
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video) for how to play video with the VideoPlayer API.

Comment: thanks a lot , thanks for your answer and also for the link you referred , it's great and exactly what I was looking for , thanks a lot ...

Comment: You are welcome!