# Mp4 file in Easy Movie Texture keeps jittering and skipping

Tags: c#, ios, video, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm building a video display in Unity 3D using the Easy Movie Texture asset and everytime I try to play my mp4 file on the video manager object my video skips and jitters (specifically in my iOS build, haven't deployed to Android yet). Has anybody else had this experience with the Easy Movie Texture with iOS? And if so, what were your solutions to solve it? Mind you I've tried OGV files and MOV files and they don't play well either.

Comment: Forget about EasyMovieTexture. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video) for how to play video in Unity.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does it work in VR as well?

Comment: Yes. It does work with VR

Comment: The nice thing about the Unity 5.6 stuff is that it'll re-transcode your videos for you if you check that box. But Easy Movie Texture also works great for me, so I'm guessing the problem is something else.