# Accessing dimensions (width/height) from a VideoPlayer source URL

Tags: c#, video, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity project that requires me to download a video file (mp4 format) and play it using the VideoPlayer component. Because the file is downloaded at runtime, I effectively have to "stream" it via a url to its downloaded location, as opposed to loading it as a VideoClip.

To accurately size the target RenderTexture and GameObject the video will be playing to, I need the dimensions of the video file itself. Because it is not a VideoClip I cannot use:

```
VideoClip clip = videoPlayer.clip;
float videoWidth = clip.width;
float videoHeight = clip.height;
```

Because I am using a source URL as opposed to a VideoClip, this will return null.

Can I get the video dimensions directly from the file somehow?

Comment: Do you get any error when you try to do `clip.width;`?

Comment: clip is null because the videoPlayer's source is set to URL rather than VideoClip.

Comment: Ok. Check back in 2 minutes.

Comment: Will using the resolution help you?
`VideoPlayer player;   
player.texture.width;   
player.texture.height;`

Comment: Initially I though it wasn't, but after checking again it seems as though you're absolutely right. Not sure how I missed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve these information from the Texture that VideoPlayer constructs.

Get VideoPlayer

```
VideoPlayer videoPlayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
```

Get the Texture VideoPlayer

```
Texture vidTex = videoPlayer.texture;
```

Get VideoPlayer dimension width/height

```
float videoWidth = vidTex.width;
float videoHeight = vidTex.height;
```

---

Make sure to only get the texture after `videoPlayer.isPrepared` is `true`. See my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154599/3785314) answer for full code on how to play video make it display on `RawImage` component.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this method already. I think I just didn't get the results I wanted (dimensions were listed as 1280 x 1280, but the video was letterboxed so I wasn't expecting a square result).  Thank you for your help (twice)!

Comment: I suspect you were accessing something else and exactly the properties from the texture in the VideoPlayer. You are welcome!