# Unity VideoPlayer is not playing audio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am struggling to get the sounds out the video from Unity Video Player.

The video is playing fine but the sound is not working.

Here is the code I use based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video) thread.

```
    public VideoClip VideoClip;
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private IEnumerator videoCoRoutine;

    void Awake()
    {
        VideoPlayer videoPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        videoPlayer.clip = VideoClip;
        videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;
        //videoPlayer.Prepare();
        videoPlayer.renderMode = VideoRenderMode.CameraNearPlane;
        videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;
        videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
        videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);
        videoPlayer.Play();
        audioSource.Play();
        //StartCoroutine(PlayVid());
        ContinueBtn.onClick.AddListener(OnContinue);
    }
```

Can anyone kindly help ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using new Unity VideoPlayer and VideoClip API to play video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video)

Comment: Seriously dude, you have to call `videoPlayer.Prepare();` after `SetTargetAudioSource`. See the duplicate. You linked to a working answer but then made a mistake. If you can't get it to work then use the code from duplicate answer like it is. Don't modify it.

Answer (score 3):

Through trial and error, here's the minimum that I've found that needs to be called to play a VideoClip from C# using Unity 2017.1 on Windows 10:

```
public class VideoPlayerTest : MonoBehaviour {

   public VideoPlayer player;
   public VideoClip clip;
   public AudioSource audioSource;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {
       player.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;
       player.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);
       player.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;
       player.clip = clip;
       player.Play();
   }
}
```

Using a GameObject configured like this:
[Unity Editor Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYCmS.png)
With this MP4 file (download and drop into your Assets directory):
https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4

Good luck! I spent a lot of time fiddling with enabling tracks/channels and it didn't seem to do anything before stumbling upon this simple configuration.