# Unity Video script not playing sound

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, video

Im using a plugin from the unity asset store and trying to get video playing with sound - currently its not. Here is the script that plays the video --

```js
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

namespace Complete360Tour {
    [AddComponentMenu("Complete360Tour/Media/VideoMediaReactor")] public class VideoMediaReactor : MonoBehaviour, IMediaSwitchReactor<VideoMediaNodeData> {
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Inspector Variables:
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        [Header("Assignment")] [SerializeField] protected MediaView mediaView;
        [SerializeField] protected VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Private Fields:
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private RenderTexture renderTexture;

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Unity Lifecycle:
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        protected void Awake() {
            if (mediaView == null) Debug.LogWarning("No MediaView assigned. Please assign a MediaView.");
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Public Methods:
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public void SwitchMedia(VideoMediaNodeData data, MediaSwitchStates state) {
            if (data == null) {
                InvalidSwitchData();
                return;
            }

            switch (state) {
                case MediaSwitchStates.BeforeSwitch: break;
                case MediaSwitchStates.Switch:
                    BeginVideo(data.VideoClip);
                    mediaView.SetStereoscopic(data.IsStereo);
                    break;
                case MediaSwitchStates.AfterSwitch: break;
            }
        }

        public void ExitMedia() { InvalidSwitchData(); }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Private Methods:
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private void InvalidSwitchData() {
            videoPlayer.Stop();
            videoPlayer.targetTexture = null;

            mediaView.SetMedia(null);
            mediaView.SetStereoscopic(false);
        }

        private void BeginVideo(VideoClip videoClip) {
            renderTexture = new RenderTexture((int) videoClip.width, (int) videoClip.height, 0);
            videoPlayer.clip = videoClip;
            videoPlayer.targetTexture = renderTexture;
            mediaView.SetMedia(renderTexture);
            videoPlayer.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding the audio stuff following

http://justcode.me/unity2d/how-to-play-videos-on-unity-using-new-videoplayer/

but no luck. Audio still wouldn't play.

Comment: Why are you using a plugin to play video when you can use Unity's [`VideoPlayer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video/41154599#41154599) to play video?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the Unity Video Player:

1. Try adding Audio Source Component to the GameObject holding the video player
2. Drag and drop the Audio source to the Audio Source in Video Player component