# Unity video playback on Android devices skips badly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video, wowza, amazon-fire-tv

So we've been fighting this for weeks. We are building a Unity (5.6 and 2017.2) app for Fire TV / Fire Stick devices (among others). It's primarily a media app sharing our own MBR content over HLS, served from a Wowza server. Every player we have tried results in the following behavior: Every two seconds or so there is a skip in the A/V playback, just a few ms or more. Some videos display this more than others, it seems. The audio and video remain in sync, just skipping frames regularly. The result is, in some cases, nearly unwatchable.

We've tried several media player plugins for Unity (UMP, NexPlayer, AvPro), and they all do the same. They play HLS content from external sources perfectly fine, but our own served content is nasty, even things we didn't encode ourselves. This is only for Unity/Android clients though; Roku and Apple TV play the content fine, as do players on Windows. It is just the confluence of Unity/Android (Fire OS, but also others) and our served content.

It seems like a Wowza setting problem but again, other clients play just fine from the same hosts. Has anyone run across this issue, and have recommendations for setting up the plugins or tweaking Wowza? Is there a specific plugin that you've successfully used as a video player in Unity, for Fire TV?

We're doing all the Unity-side things correctly we think. (Multithreaded GL rendering, etc.)

Comment: Use Unity's [VideoPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video/41154599#41154599) API. Have you tried that?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't support MBR video like HLS or DASH.

Comment: That sucks. Those plugins you mentioned are not free so I suggest you contact the publisher of them and report the issue. They should be able to fix it.

Comment: We contacted AvPro, who has never seen the issue. I'm still coming up on Wowza (I'm mostly not a server dev, and MBR streaming is new to me). There might be some things there, but I dunno.

Comment: Ok. Also give Easy Movie Texture  a try. It's not free but supports HLS.

Comment: Managed to solve this using avPro's new release. It seems to make better use of ExoPlayer underneath. Yaaay