# unity output EasyMoveTexture audio to unity AudioSource

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i'm currently using [Easy Movie Texture](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/easy-movie-texture-video-texture-10032) unity plugin to play video file in android. it work ok, my question is how to output this plugin audio to unity AudioSource to use AudioSource.GetSpectrumData?

in sum how can output the audio played by android plugin to unity AusioSource?

Comment: Why can't you use Unity's [`VideoPlayer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video?s=3|69.6578) API? You definitely use `AudioSource.GetSpectrumData` with it.

Comment: @Programmer Problem is VideoPlayer play with lag most time...