# How would I put a video in this Unity sample game (Trash Dash)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video, android-video-player, assetbundle

I have put a Video Player component into [this Unity sample game](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/endless-runner-sample-game-87901) project to see if it's possible, but when I put it on Android it doesn't play and Logcat says the video can't be found. The Video Player Component has been placed on a plane added to one of the early track segments, and it works fine on Android, but when I built the project and ran it on Android it was just a plain white billboard.

Apparently the reason for this is because AssetBundles does not support video content yet, so I've tried to bypass AssetBundles by linking to an URL. This actually worked when the URL was pointing to an .mp4 file hosted on a web server, but the app was re-downloading it every time a new instance of the game was made, meaning it would put the server under heavy load, sometimes the video just wouldn't play before it was already behind the player. For a better (but very temporary) solution, I tried changing the URL to point to a copy of the file on the testing tablet (a Huawei MediaPad M5)'s downloads folder (file:///storage/emulated/0/download/Placeholder%20Video.mp4, which lets me access the video in Android Chrome). This hasn't worked so far, and I think it has something to do with permissions. On the other hand, I'm concerned that I'm barking up the wrong tree for what is only a temporary workaround.

Comment: Have you had a look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154599/1299146. It states something about the `StreamingAssets` folder files staying as-is and you would just access it by URI from code to the Android file system

Comment: Thanks, this is what worked!